# android studio: send specific message to a specific contact by Whatsapp

Tags: android, android-studio

with the following code I'm successfully make it to the contact Whatsapp contact page, but it send nothing.
what do I need to add?

```
   String whatsappId = "+972506476784"+"@s.whatsapp.net";
   Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:" + whatsappId);
   Intent waIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,uri);
   //waIntent.setType("text/plain");
   String text = "HI";
   PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
   //Check if package exists or not. If not then code
   //in catch block will be called
    waIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
    waIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
    waIntent.putExtra("chat",true);
    startActivity(waIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't send message to specific contact or group.

WhatsApp Official doc : [I'm an Android developer, how can I integrate WhatsApp with my app](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012)

> There are two ways to integrate with WhatsApp:
>
> - **Through a custom URL scheme**
>     Opening ***whatsapp://send?text=*** followed by the text to send, will open WhatsApp, allow the user to choose a contact, and pre-fill the input field with the specified text.
> - **Through Android's intent system**
>
>   Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
>     sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
>     sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
>     sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
>     sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
>     startActivity(sendIntent);